# powerful javascript canvas libraries

Tags: javascript, canvas

As a simple javascript library, we have jquery which is very powerful. But I want to know which are some of the powerful canvas library in terms of usability, flexibility and versatility.

I found Raphael to be pretty interesting, but I found it has less effects. So I am looking for a canvas library with has a lot animation effects and flexibility working with SVG and canvas elements.

Comment: This closure seems to be misunderstood. Editing and voting to reopen.

Comment: My vote to reopen too. Good answers to these questions mean finding the correct libraries, which can save days if not months of someone's time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Fabric.js](http://badassjs.com/post/1021168983/fabric-js-an-interactive-object-model-and-svg-parser) looks pretty sweet.

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/ its the Fabric.js Home Page

Answer (score 8):

You are essentially asking the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fram). That will give you a good idea of what stackoverflow users use.

You can also refer to [this](http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/drawing/10-best-javascript-drawing-and-canvas-libraries/) link to see the top 10 best open javascript libraries.

I take into consideration both links and weigh them against the performance needs of your application.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Starx asked first!   Good catch on tracking down a well answered SO though!

Comment: Heh, didn't actually notice how old this thread was.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/drawing/10-best-javascript-drawing-and-canvas-libraries/) you may find what you're looking for.

The list presents a good selection of JavaScript Drawing and Canvas Libraries.

Comment: I have already googled @studiosjoseph, I want to know from the users who have actually used canvas libraries

Comment: Have you used a canvas library before, if you have which do you think is more powerful among them