# What is the current state of the art in HTML canvas JavaScript libraries and frameworks?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, html, canvas

I am currently investigating options for working with the canvas in a new HTML 5 application, and was wondering what is the current state of the art in HTML canvas JavaScript libraries and frameworks?

In particular, are there frameworks that support the kind of things needed for game development - complex animation, managing scene graphs, handling events and user interactions?

Also willing to consider both commercial and open source products.

Comment: If you're using scene graphs and handling events, isn't SVG better suited to your needs?

Comment: Well, that's part of the reason I ask. Canvas definitely has the momentum atm, so trying to ascertain what's feasible and what isn't. SVG doesn't scale particular well when it comes to complex animations.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for 3D graphics, or 2D, or either one?

Comment: Another nice demo here: http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/asteroids/. Not sure if the library they've created is available for all to use. A nice example of canvas though.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/user/zlatnaspirala/fiddles/ try this framework visualJS.

Answer (score 96):

[image: Fabric.js screenshot]

I've been working on **fabric.js** — a canvas library to help with exactly that — manipulating objects on canvas, by handling events and user interactions. It's not released yet, but take a look at a simple [preview demo](http://fabricjs.com/test/demo/).

You can also see it in action in [this design editor](http://printio.ru/ringer_man_tees/new), which it was originally created for.

**Edit:** The project is [now available on github](http://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) (open-sourced under MIT License)

To get started, check out:

- [Demos](http://fabricjs.com/demos/) (simple & complex, with code to show how they're done)
- [Fabric.js presentation at FalsyValues](http://www.slideshare.net/kangax/fabric-falsy-values-8067834/) (and [another one at BK.js](http://www.slideshare.net/kangax/fabricjs-building-acanvaslibrarybk))
- [Wiki on github](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki) (including [FAQ](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/FAQ))
- [Documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/)
- [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/fabricjs) (ask any question there)
- [Fabric.js on twitter](http://twitter.com/fabricjs) (or short questions via twitter)
- [Introduction to Fabric.js: Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj714178.aspx) (article on ScriptJunkie)
- [Introduction to Fabric.js: Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj856929.aspx) (article on ScriptJunkie)

How does Fabric compare to other Javascript canvas libraries? Here's a [comparison table](http://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0).

Comment: What does it do on IE? ExplorerCanvas?

Comment: That is a phenomenal demo, extremely impressive project

Comment: @musicfreak Yes, ExplorerCanvas. Btw, it passes all ~900 tests in IE9 (4th preview), using its native canvas support.

Comment: Is there a project page for fabric.js anywhere?  I'm pretty interested in learning more about it.

Comment: Whoa, just what I need... I actually was frustrated with how difficult it was to manage functions this library so seamlessly handles!

Comment: @nubegeek101 I've updated the answer with some links to demos/examples that could come in helpful.

Answer (score 17):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned [WebGL](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/), and frameworks built on it. I would consider it high on the list for state-of-the-art for 3D GPU-accelerated graphics and complex animation on HTML canvas / javascript.

> WebGL is a cross-platform,
> royalty-free web standard for a
> low-level 3D graphics API based on
> OpenGL ES 2.0, exposed through the
> HTML5 Canvas element as Document
> Object Model  interfaces. ...
>
> WebGL
> brings plugin-free 3D to the web,
> implemented right into the browser.
> Major browser vendors Apple (Safari),
> Google (Chrome), Mozilla (Firefox),
> and Opera (Opera) are members of the
> WebGL Working Group.

WebGL is very solid in its support for GPU-accelerated graphics. Check out these GLSL [shader](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2010/08/10/using-webgl-glsl-shaders-to-create-a-tunnel-effect/) [demos](http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/index.php/2010/02/shader-toy/). :-) And see [ChemDoodle](http://web.chemdoodle.com/overview.php) as an example of user interaction.

I've been working on an app using Google's [O3D](http://code.google.com/p/o3d/) framework, which manages the scene graph, and uses WebGL for rendering (it used to use its own plug-in). O3D is a work in progress, and its documentation is not completely up to date, but it is under active development, and there are some [good demos out there](http://code.google.com/p/o3d/wiki/Samples). [3D Pool](http://o3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples_webgl/o3d-webgl-samples/pool.html) may be most up your alley. The Google developers are very responsive to questions in the discussion group.

There are a number of other frameworks built on WebGL; [see here](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/User_Contributions#Frameworks). Ones that mention game development and scene graphs include Copperlicht, SceneJS, X3DOM.

WebGL runs in recent development builds of [several browsers](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Getting_a_WebGL_Implementation), but not IE. I've been using Firefox ("Minefield") and Chromium with good results. You will need one of these to run the above demos.

However if your requirements are that it must have no dependencies beyond HTML 5 canvas / js, WebGL may not be the right choice. It [doesn't look like IE will support it](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=993) anytime soon.

**Update:** after putting up a lot of resistance, MS [decided to support WebGL in IE 11](http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/26/microsoft-confirms-webgl-support-for-internet-explorer-11/).

Comment: Three.js is run on webgl

Comment: @nube: good point. Three.js can render on WebGL, SVG, or plain (2D) canvas.

Answer (score 15):

[**three.js**](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/), by [mr. doob](http://mrdoob.com/), is a fantastic 3d engine for javascript that includes scenegraph (both software and WebGL/hardware accelerated versions), shading, particles, skinned animation (i think), and lighting effects. Check it out, he is a super-talented fellow.

I should add that you are going to need the newest Google Chrome or equivalent to view most of the demos, one of my favorites is: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cars.html

Comment: This demo is actually even better : http://carvisualizer.plus360degrees.com/threejs/

Answer (score 13):

KineticJS is an up-and-coming library that boasts creating and animating individual "layers" on the canvas for high performance.

http://www.kineticjs.com/

Comment: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/#mothballed says "_I will no longer be maintaining this repo or the official KineticJS website because I have moved onto other ventures and projects_" and GitHub reports 147 open issues

Answer (score 8):

CAKE.js is no longer being maintained but is a fairly powerful framework - http://code.google.com/p/cakejs/

Demos here - http://glimr.rubyforge.org/cake/canvas.html, http://glimr.rubyforge.org/cake/missile_fleet.html

Comment: Awesome. Looks pretty sophisticated. And in a world of OS, you are only 1 enthusiast away from being actively maintained :)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [processingjs](http://processingjs.org/) framework. Also the upcoming mootools version 2.0 has the [art projekt](http://github.com/kamicane/art) to work with canvas

Comment: ProcessingJS is an interesting approach to the problem, but it's essentially a procedural DSL implemented in JavaScript, not sure it can scale to non-trivial applications. Will check the MooTools option.

Comment: Yeah, Processing is a data viz prototyping language.  The fact that there's a Javascript port is neat, but that hardly makes it an HTML 5 framework.

Comment: The question was about a canvas framework not html5, and thats whats processingJS is.

Comment: Pardon my semantics error. Canvas framework is what I was getting at.

Answer (score 6):

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) seems a pretty good canvas library; it's SVG-based (or VML-based in Internet Explorer), and thus supports a lot of user input events. It's fairly small (60kb gzipped), so isn't too large a dependency.

It seems to have a nice tweener too: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#animate (see [here](http://raphaeljs.com/bounce.html) and [here](http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html) for examples).

For an example of what it can do, have a look at [this clever little demo](http://raphaeljs.com/scape/).

Comment: SVG is not the same thing as canvas though

Answer (score 4):

I have found two libraries to be extremely competitive and much better then fabric.

Kinetic.js and easel.js both have extremely good event handling, grouping and general shape abstraction. You'll find a lot to love in both of these; easel seems to have more image oriented and filtering.

Fabric's event handlins is MUCH worse than either of these - basically it treats the whole canvas as one big event rrapper and tells you when "Something" has been clicked on. It doesn't attach events to individual shapes or groups of shapes.

Comment: FWIW, Fabric now allows you to attach events directly to objects and has generic group functionality.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [interesting library](http://www.davidflanagan.com/2010/07/cantojs-an-impr.html) that aims to improve some of the fundamentals of working with the canvas API called [canto.js](http://ajaxian.com/archives/canto-js-an-improved-canvas-api) by David Flanagan, author of [Javascript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565923928).

Comment: Might be a useful foundation for a framework that handles the higher-level stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Also, young, but not bad, Javascript framework, and it (complex animation, managing scene graphs, handling events and user interactions) all about it - [jCanvaScript](http://jcscript.com). May be, except 'managing scene graphs'.

Answer (score 3):

Been working with bHive to produce graphs and moving site headers, seems impressive and powerful, unlike the others seems to be being developed. Adobe Edge is also worth a gander though strictly not Canvas.

http://www.bhivecanvas.com

and

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/

Answer (score 2):

Aves Engine is really really great: http://www.dextrose.com/en/projects/aves-engine

Also, Akihabara seems good: http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/

Comment: Aves is unreleased and apparently doesn't use canvas. Pretty impressive demos though.

Comment: Aves doesn't use canvas at all, take a look at this: http://paulbakaus.com/2010/07/19/why-canvas-is-not-an-obvious-choice-for-web-games/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Javascript, Dojo is a great way to go.  It has a compact, cross-platform (SVG, VML, Canvas, Silverlight) vector graphics API that is very powerful.  You can find it in dojo.gfx and dojox.gfx.

We've used this to build an interactive physics tutor that allows students to draw vectors, ellipses, etc (even append images) and perform all sorts of transformations on them.  You can see what we've done at http://gideon.eas.asu.edu/web-UI/login.html --just login with any username.

I've taken a look at fabric.js and dojox.drawing does a lot of the same things.  If you look at the tests in the toolkit (once you've got it its dojox/drawing/tests/) you find examples of everything from vector graphics to images to programmatically created shadows.

Answer (score 1):

I am impressed with Akihabara as a game engine.  It has fantastic documentation in the form of tutorials and an api. I've even seen on some message boards talk of an akihabara 2 release.  Unfortunately, all that talk is about one year or more old. I really hope this engine is still being developed.

Answer (score 1):

I just released the first iteration of a new drawing & tweening library geared towards folks with an AS3/Flash development background. While my lib doesn't yet support complex drawing paths or graphs *per se* I'm hoping it'll help folks quickly draw & animate basic primitives in a familiar way.

Feedback and comments are welcome.
http://www.quietless.com/kitchen/introducing-js3/