# Which technology to use for online, user-friendly product customization, with custom text and images?

Tags: jquery, html, image, graphics, rotation

I'm looking to create something similar to this product customizer:

http://www.tastyimagechocolate.com/edible-photos?product_id=238 (Click "Personalize")

Key features:

- Ability to add text or/and images
- Text styling (rotation, color, font size etc)
- Text or image does not go beyond the product shape (in above case, a heart).
- Drag and drop

Are there any open source plugins already out there that I would be able to implement for this (not looking for drawing pads)?

Otherwise, the only other option I see is coding from scratch using jQuery, tackling each feature by itself, one by one (as I did find code snippets such as rotation, drag and drop etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the source code I've found kineticjs is being used. Seems it offers all functionality I mentioned in my OP.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/

More info on other similar libraries: 
[Current State of Javascript Canvas Libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938969/current-state-of-javascript-canvas-libraries)