# How to Animate Drawing in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to HTML5. I have an animated sequence inside a canvas that shows a pencil writing different letters like ABC etc. I would like to have this saved and available for playback as a tutorial for the user who would then try and write ABC on the canvas themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fra) -- this topic has been touched on before on SO.

It might also be worth considering using an SVG library like [raphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) instead of canvas -- this would greatly simply your life if you were planning on including any interactivity with these tutorials, and they would certainly make glyph rendering especially easy (using [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)).