# make clickable region in canvas to change image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Please help me:

- create clickable regions in the canvas below that I can assign onmousedown= events to.  I know how to do this with invisible DIVs, but I think there is a more elegant way to do it in canvas that I don't know.
- when I click one of the regions, want to pass an image name to a function so that it changes the image being displayed to another image, and then changes it back onmouseup.

if you show me just one region and one mousedown/mouseup example I can do the rest...thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="506" height="319" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
        </canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        };
        img.src="firstImage.gif";
        </script>

        /////////HERE NEED/////////
                    CREATE CLICKABLE REGION <region>
                    <region>
                    onmousedown=changeCanvasImage(secondImage.gif) //change image on click
                    onmouseup=changeCanvasImage(firstImage.gif)  /change it back when done
        </region>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canvas element can fire events but graphical elements within the canvas cannot. To do this you'll either need to implement it yourself by detecting the [position of the mouse on the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677/how-do-i-get-the-coordinates-of-a-mouse-click-on-a-canvas-element) when it is clicked and relating the value to something in your canvas, or using one of the many [canvas libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fra) available which will handle the detection for you.