# Change gradient color on HTML5 canvas mouseover

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, gradient

I'm trying to change canvas color (gradient) on mouseover.

Now I have this code - http://jsfiddle.net/juodikis/p7htB/4/

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just parameterize your drawing function and then add the mouseover/mouseout events to your canvas to call the draw function with different parameters.

> canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
>       draw("#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff");
>   });
>
> canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
>       draw("#474747", "#6a6a6a", "#b9b9b9");
>   });​

where

> var draw = function(color1, color2, shadow) {
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>   var lingrd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 195);
>   lingrd.addColorStop(1, color1);
>   lingrd.addColorStop(0, color2);
>   context.fillStyle = lingrd;
>   context.shadowColor = shadow;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> }

You can see this working in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/p7htB/7/)

Comment: And how it should be for separated blocks? For example I move my mouse over first one and only first one changes color. Is it possible?

Comment: To do that, you would need a mechanism for mouse detection. This a more complex issue to address. If you need this kind of functionality, you'd probably do better by using some kind of canvas framework. You can find a discussion about some of the existing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474608/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-html-canvas-javascript-libraries-and-fra)