# CSS/HTML: Border builds it self?

Tags: html, css

so I am wondering how this is possible? I really would like something similar to this on my site. 
How hard is this to do and if so can anyone help me?

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:
[Click Here](https://gyazo.com/edcbf2e81f9692cb244f7df9db642430)

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your link doesn't have anything to do with borders; it shows someone clicking a button and moving a mouse cursor.

Comment: If you saw the image, after the person clicked "play" you can see the text "play zen gaming" and around it was a border that built itself up.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't very clear. Well, you could do something with a background image in a div with overflow:hidden and a transitioning width.

Comment: A transitioning width?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to animate drawing lines on canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939588/how-to-animate-drawing-lines-on-canvas)

Comment: I mean a width that starts out from 0 and grows to the width iof the window with a `transition` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, are you wondering if you can accomplish that in pure HTML and CSS?

## Yes, you can.

To simulate border–drawing animation, all you need to do is use some `svg` and perform a trick with animating an SVG stroke (border).

The trick in its simplest form consists of:

1. `svg` element — it'll contain our vector graphic, it's important to include `viewbox` attribute for proper scaling,
2. `path` or any other SVG element that can have a stroke,
3. `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` CSS properties for our `path`. We begin with something big, such as `stroke-dashoffset: 2000px`,
4. `animation` CSS property along with `@keyframes` to bring `stroke-dashoffset` back to `0` after defined amount of time.

## Understanding stroke offset

In SVG you can create dashed border — so it consists of alternating parts: gaps and stroke. `stroke-dasharray` defines this behaviour. It expects **at least** 2 numbers. The first one being width of a dash and the second one — width of the gap.

Moreover, `stroke-dashoffset` just controls the offset of this dash–gap pair. In other words, it's a number that defines where the first dash will begin.

I prepared an example which shows relationship between those 2 properties. You can play with it by clicking **Run code snippet**. ;-)

```css
svg {
  transition: all 1s;
}

#dasharray-1:checked ~ #preview svg {
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 20px;
}
#dasharray-2:checked ~ #preview svg {
  stroke-dasharray: 20px 10px;
}
#dasharray-3:checked ~ #preview svg {
  /*/ dash 10px / gap 20px / dash 30px / gap 40px... /*/
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
}
#dasharray-4:checked ~ #preview svg {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000px 2000px;
}

#dashoffset-1:checked ~ #preview svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 100px;
}
#dashoffset-2:checked ~ #preview svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 1990px;
}
#dashoffset-3:checked ~ #preview svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 2000px;
}

h1,
h2{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: .5em;
}

#preview {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 1em;
  transform-origin: 100% 0%;
}
```

```html
<h1>SVG test</h1>
<h2><code>stroke-dasharray</code></h2>
<input type="radio" name="dasharray" id="dasharray-0" checked>
<label for="dasharray-0"><code>default</code></label>
<input type="radio" name="dasharray" id="dasharray-1">
<label for="dasharray-1"><code>10px 20px</code></label>
<input type="radio" name="dasharray" id="dasharray-2">
<label for="dasharray-2"><code>20px 10px</code></label>
<input type="radio" name="dasharray" id="dasharray-3">
<label for="dasharray-3"><code>10px 20px 30px 40px</code></label>
<input type="radio" name="dasharray" id="dasharray-4">
<label for="dasharray-4"><code>2000px 2000px</code></label>

<h2><code>stroke-dashoffset</code></h2>
<input type="radio" name="dashoffset" id="dashoffset-0" checked>
<label for="dashoffset-0"><code>default</code></label>
<input type="radio" name="dashoffset" id="dashoffset-1">
<label for="dashoffset-1"><code>100px</code></label>
<input type="radio" name="dashoffset" id="dashoffset-2">
<label for="dashoffset-2"><code>1990px</code></label>
<input type="radio" name="dashoffset" id="dashoffset-3">
<label for="dashoffset-3"><code>2000px</code></label>

<div id="preview">
  <h2>Preview</h2>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="150">
    <rect width="100" height="150" fill="none" stroke="#222" stroke-width="10" color="#000"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

## Fancy example

Now that you (hopefully) understand how strokes work, you are ready for some magic! To animate a drawing effect, first we define a pair of dash–and–gap. Dash will have a width of 2000px, and the same goes for a gap — `stroke-dashoffset: 2000px 2000px`. Then we move those, so only a gap is visible to the user — `stroke-dashoffset: 2000px`. Finally, we set off an animation which results in the offset going back to `0` — `stroke-dashoffset: 0`.

```css
/*/ Animate lines /*/
.ornament .line path {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #ecf0f1;
 stroke-width: .2px;
 stroke-dasharray: 2000px 2000px;
 stroke-dashoffset: 2000px;
 animation: drawStroke 5s ease-in-out forwards 0s;
}

@keyframes drawStroke {
 to {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
 }
}

/*/ Arrange our 4 exact SVGs /*/
.ornament {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.ornament.bottom {
 transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.ornament .line {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.ornament .line.left {
 transform: scaleX(-1);
}

/*/ Add gradient /*/
.ornament {
 position: relative;
}
.ornament:before,
.ornament:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 background: red;
 width: 40%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 pointer-events: none;
}
.ornament:before {
 left: 0;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #111 0%, transparent 100%); 
}
.ornament:after {
 right: 0;
 background: linear-gradient(to left, #111 0%, transparent 100%); 
}

/*/ Beauty /*/
body {
 background: #111;
 color: #fff;
}
header {
 text-align: center;
 color: lime;
 font: 2em Impact, sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
header .title {
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="games">
  <header>
    <div class="ornament top">
      <svg class="line left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 186 26">
        <path d="M0 1.4h11L18 12 7.3 9.4l6.4-2L9.3 3 2.6 4.6l6 1.6L3 1l4 14.4L13 5 2.8 11l24.4 6.4H130l14 8h42"/>
      </svg>
      <svg class="line right" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 186 26">
        <path d="M0 1.4h11L18 12 7.3 9.4l6.4-2L9.3 3 2.6 4.6l6 1.6L3 1l4 14.4L13 5 2.8 11l24.4 6.4H130l14 8h42"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <h2 class="title">
      Play now
    </h2>
    <div class="ornament bottom">
      <svg class="line left" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 186 26">
        <path d="M0 1.4h11L18 12 7.3 9.4l6.4-2L9.3 3 2.6 4.6l6 1.6L3 1l4 14.4L13 5 2.8 11l24.4 6.4H130l14 8h42"/>
      </svg>
      <svg class="line right" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 186 26">
        <path d="M0 1.4h11L18 12 7.3 9.4l6.4-2L9.3 3 2.6 4.6l6 1.6L3 1l4 14.4L13 5 2.8 11l24.4 6.4H130l14 8h42"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </header>
</section>
```